# Compile Error: Expected Case

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have an event procedure of the form to `Execute` a series of 
Append query statements to create the new related records. I am getting a "Compile Error: Expected Case" the `SELECT Inquiries.InquiryID` of the code is red. The exact code is pasted below.

```vb
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
   Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO PreCallQuestionaireResidential ( InquiryID )"
    SELECT Inquiries.InquiryID
    FROM Inquiries
     db.Execute strSQL
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Access sees `SELECT` unquoted, it expects that to be part of a `Select Case` code block.

You want your `SELECT` included in the `strSQL` string ...

```vb
strSQL = "INSERT INTO PreCallQuestionaireResidential ( InquiryID )" & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT Inquiries.InquiryID FROM Inquiries"
Debug.Print strSQL '<- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
```

Comment: Also, for better information in the event of problems, consider using the *dbFailOnError* option with `db.Execute strSQL`